# Add a new sheet to excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a new sheet to my workbook and I was able to find some suggestions online. I ended up using this piece of code but for some reason, it is not working. I don't know why because to me the logic makes sense and there seems to be no problem with the syntax. I am guessing it's something I can't see and since I am new to VBA I could really use someone's input.

```
Private Sub PopulateTaskList()

'Adds new sheet called task list
    Dim exists As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
   
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = "Task List" Then
        exists = True
        Else
            If exists = False Then
                Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Task List"
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `Sheets` instead of `Worksheets`? They are not the exact same thing.

Comment: I just googled how to add a new sheet to my workbook in google and that's what showed up. Like I said I  am new to vba so I could totally be wrong, should I use worksheets?

Comment: Quick update I was able to solve my issue thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Exit Sub` instead when it's detected.

That way, if it makes it out of the loop (but not out of the sub), you know it hasn't been created yet.

```
Private Sub EnsureTaskListSheetExists()
    'Adds new sheet called task list
    Dim i As Integer
   
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = "Task List" Then Exit Sub
    Next
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Task List"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help I was able to solve it! I wanted to know if there is a way to make vba delete that sheet once the user closes out of excel.

Comment: There are events for that, yes. Try something and then ask another question if you have problems with that.